# How to obtain Microsoft Message Compiler (mc.exe)?

Tags: windows

I'm building a project with g++ whose build system requires invoking [mc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385638(v=vs.85).aspx) as a step.

What's the simplest way to obtain this little standalone utility -- preferably without having to install gigabytes worth of other stuff I don't need? (the smallest Windows SDK option seems to be about 1.5 GB)

I'm on a Windows 10 Home system that has never had any Windows SDK, nor MSVC installed, and I have checked in the usual locations that it is not installed already (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\` do not contain it).

Answer (score 6):

On my machine, it is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\mc.exe .

I have the Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.16299.0 installed. This was installed as part of the installation of Visual Studio 2017 with C++ components. This location was not in the PATH by default, I had to add it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The message compiler is part of the Windows SDK and installs to \Program files (x86)\windows kits\bin\

Message compiler command lines are described here [MSDN : MC.EXE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385638(v=vs.85).aspx)

SDK download is currently [Microsoft : SDK download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: Do you know which sub-component of Windows SDK includes mc.exe? I'd like to install as little as possible